# Missing output for C program with command line execution

Tags: c, command-line

I am trying to build a C program which will take the WIFI quality and signal level at different intervals. I  have the command line execution and parsing etc for the quality but the signal level doesnt get saved. I tried `echo quality=45/70 Signal level=-75 dbs` and this code snippet works perfectly but not for the real command line code. I cant figure out why it would work for quality but not signal strength? Apologies for the code quality I only just started learning C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

FILE *in;
extern FILE *popen();
char buff[512];
char str[60]={" "};
char ssid[40]={""};
char quality[6]={""};
char level[5]={""};
char temp[2];

if(!(in = popen("iwlist wlan0 scan | grep -e 'Signal level' ", "r"))){
    exit(1);
}


int turn=1;
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
    strcat(str, buff);

    int z;
    for(z=0;z<30;z++){

        if(str[z] == '='){
            printf("\n ::::: %s", str);
            z++;
            int limit;
            if(str[z]=='-'){
                int y;
                limit=z+4;
                for(y=z; y< limit; y++, z++){

                    sprintf(temp, "%c", str[y]);
                    strcat(level, temp);
                }
            }else{
                int x;
                limit=z+5;
                for(x=z; x<limit ; x++, z++){

                    sprintf(temp, "%c", str[x]);
                    strcat(quality, temp);
                }
                printf("\n ::::: %s", str);
            }

        }
    }
}   
printf("\n printing quality::::: %s", quality);
printf("\n printing signal level:::::: %s", level);
printf("\n ::::: %s", str);
pclose(in);  
}
```

Each of the print str prints the full proper string: Quality= ... Signal level=-... 
Quality prints correctly but level is blank.

Thanks in advance
Philip

Comment: you may wanna make sure that `str` is big enough in `strcat(str,buff)` since it keeps on appending to str, maybe you meant strcpy?

Comment: Hi Claptrap... I tried that with no joy.

Comment: str has size 60, buff has size 512. It could even crash on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: maybe you could call the command `iwlist ... | grep -e ....` from command shell and post what exactly you get. The way you copy the values into `quality` and `level` are far too complicated, but they should work

Comment: Hi Ingo Leonhardt. I get the correct output from command shell. Hi joop, both str and buff at 512 also doesnt work.

Comment: I believe you output is correct, but for parsing it's neccessary to know how **exactly** it looks

Comment: code:`
 :::::                      Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  

 :::::                      Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  

 printing quality::::: 33/70
 printing signal level:::::: 
 :::::                      Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm`

Comment: command line: Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm

Comment: ok, the output you've posted shows at least that your parser loop doesn't find the second '=' (':::: Quality=...' yould have been printed three times otherwise). At the moment I can't see why

Comment: Is there an easier solution or different method possibly?